# CORS on localhost to test an app?

Tags: angularjs, web-services, cakephp

I'm trying test an app on browser. The problem is that my webservice is it in localhost also and when I try execute some request to the webservice does returns of CORS exception says **same origin policy**. Looking for solutions I found a way to disable CORS on Firefox executing this way: `about:config -> security.fileuri.strict_origin_policy -> false` but doesn't works.

How could I solve this ?

I created the webservice with CakePHP.

**CakePHP webservice function**

```
/** do login in app */
public function doLogin(){            
            $this->autoRender = false;
            $this->response->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
            $this->response->type('json');                
            $retorno = array("email"=>"me@gmail.com", "senha"=>"senha");            
            return json_encode($retorno);
}
```

**Tried add in beforeRender of controller also**

```
public function beforeRender() {
            header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
            parent::beforeRender();
        }
```

**AngularJS**

```
var app = angular.module("starter");

app.service("UserLoginAPI", function($http, AppConstants, Base64){
    this.doLogin = function(User){
        var _url = "http://localhost/AppPanel/users/doLogin.json";
        var _authdata = Base64.encode(User.email + ':' + User.senha);

        var _headers = {
                'Authorization': 'Basic ' + _authdata,
                'Accept': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'               
            };

        return $http({
            method: 'POST',             
            url: _url,              
            headers: _headers               
            });         

    };
});
```

Comment: There is more to CORS than a single header ... see http://stackoverflow.com/a/9866124/1175966 for pure php solution. Likely will find cake integrations also with some searching. Important to make sure you are handling OPTIONS requests

Comment: Also your `post` is set up incorrectly. The posted data should be second argument and the config object should have `headers` as a property

Comment: @charlietfl ups, I posted the return of post wrong. now is ok. If I execute on device does works fine but on browser not because CORS

Comment: Should be easy enough to enable cors using solution above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the problem. I added these parameters in Chrome shortcut and now works fine. `--args --allow-file-access-from-files --disable-web-security`